# Combining Costs and Priors with ROC Curves

Tags: r, roc, prior

While studying ROC curves, I came across the idea of misclassification costs and prior probabilities. ROC tells us about the sensitivity and speficity, while not considering the cost and priors. I wanted to know, if there is a way that we can combine both cost and priors, or consider them jointly in our ROC curve?

Thank you